# Clicking on marker cluster wants to open spider with exact same location markers by default

Tags: markerclusterer

I was trying to implement MarkerCluster (MS) with 
Overlapping Marker Cluster (OMS). Everything seems to work just fine.

However,  I am looking to modify the way OMS is works so that if I click on a cluster that has 2 points under it

When I click on any Cluster with 2 points in it with exact same geo location, its opens a marker and when I am clicking on that marker it's opening spider with 2 markers.

What I want when I am clicking on the 
Cluster, straight a way it will open up spider with 2 markers, already 
spend lot of times but still nothing worked.

I already tried many solutions, like

1.
I can track the marker when I am adding to OMS(oms.addMarker), and can 
click depending on zoom_changed event of google map, but its not firing 
spiderfy rather its firing click event of what we added to markers.....

2.
I have see a event spiderfy, so I tried to trigger that event with a 
marker object (oms.trigger('spiderfy', marker);) but nothing working...

Here I am adding code snippet too:

`mc = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers.locations, mcOptions);
google.maps.event.addListener(mc, 'clusterclick', function(cluster) {`
enter code here`clusterClicked = true;
    // HERE WE WANTS TO FIRE SPIDER FUNCTIONALITY ...
});`

Answer (score 1):

I could solve this problem, first of all it is obvious that you have implemented and Overlapping Xluster Marker Marker Cluster in your google maps.

My solution is something very simple.

1. We capture the click event of markerCluster.
2. obtain the markers of markerCluster.
3. check whether all the markerCluster markers are in the same position.
4. if they are in the same position we make a click event trigger the latter obtained the markerCluster marker.

In short this is the code:

```
       var markerClusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, allMarkers, {styles: styles[0], clusterClass: 'poiCluster', maxZoom:18}); 
       google.maps.event.addListener(markerClusterer, 'click', function(cluster) {

        var markers = cluster.getMarkers();

        if(estanTodosEnLaMismaPosicion(markers)){
             //to wait for map update
            setTimeout(function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markers.length-1], 'click');
            },1000)
        }



        return true;
    });




    function estanTodosEnLaMismaPosicion(markers){
    var cont=0;
    var latitudMaster=markers[0].getPosition().lat();
    var longitudMaster=markers[0].getPosition().lng();
    for(var i=0;i<markers.length;i++){
        if(markers[i].getPosition().lat() === latitudMaster & markers[i].getPosition().lng() === longitudMaster ){
            cont++;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
    if(cont==markers.length){
        return true;
    }else if(cont<markers.length){
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking on how to trigger the OMS instead of MarkerClusterer, but this way doesn't work for me. By the way, you can simply return cont==markers.length instead of the if else condition